# Visual Studio not rounding decimals

Tags: reporting-services, decimal, rounding

Is there a way where I can get the #.# not to return as rounding to the nearest tenths place?

Example: For FY15 I need 4.0 to return but right now the only way I see that 4.0 is when I add the hundredths place 4.08.

Don't want: 4.08
Want: 4.0

Is there a way to accomplish this?

If I palce the number with 2 decmials, the #.## is correct. Example below.

[image]

However, when i place the number with 1 decimal, the number rounds up to the nearest tenths place. I don't want that. Example below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `floor` function on your values. 
Example: 4.08

First, to preserve the first decimal place, multiply by 10.0. This gives 40.8.
Now use the floor function on 40.8, which gives 40.0. 
Finally, divide by 10.0 to return to the degree of the original number, giving 4.0.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I've placed the expression: =FLOOR(Fields!AnnualAvg.Value*10.0)/10.0. However, its still shows 2 decimal places.

Comment: Sorry it works! I had the formatting Number set to 2 decimal places. I changed it to 1 and it's returning 1 decimal place. Thanks again!